# How to debug an error "'X' was not declared in this scope" in C?

Tags: c

```
/* Converting Fahrenheit to Kelvin */

#include <stdio.h>

int 
main (void)

{

int fahr,
double kelvin;

     printf ("Enter input \n");
     scanf("%d", &fahr);
     kelvin = 5/9 (fahr-32) + 273.15);
     printf ("you get %f. \n", kelvin)

   return (0);  
}
```

The errors I get are:

> line 13 column 1:   expected unqualified-id before 'double' 17    6   :
>   'kelvin' was not declared in this scope 17    27  :   [Error] expression
>   cannot be used as a function 28       :   recipe for target
>   'Project1edit.o' failed

I am using Dev-C++ to write this code.  This is my first program in C.

Comment: int fahr;
use semicolon for ending a statement.
also use "*" for performing multiplication.
Try to read the basic syntax followed in C.

Comment: I added * between 5/9 and (fahr-32).  Is that what you mean?  Now I have two errors.. one saying it expected a ';' before ')' which makes no sense.  That would be (.... + 273.15;);

Comment: 1) `int fahr,` --> `int fahr;` 2) `kelvin = 5/9 (fahr-32) + 273.15);` --> `kelvin = 5.0/9 * (fahr-32) + 273.15;` 3) `printf ("you get %f. \n", kelvin)` --> `printf ("you get %f. \n", kelvin);`

Comment: then I still have "recipe for target 'Project1edit.o' failed.  That is the name of my project, 'Project1edit.'

Comment: why do I get negatives for my questions.  I don't know how to be any clearer about my confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a correction in your code.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
        float fahr;
        double kelvin;

        printf ("Enter input \n");
        scanf("%f", &fahr);

        kelvin = (5.0 / 9.0 * (fahr - 32) + 273.15);
        printf("you get %.2f\n", kelvin);
}
```

Also, You missed the multiplication operator, `*` and brace `(`.

```
kelvin = (5/9 *(fahr-32) + 273.15);
```

Also, solved syntax error in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Your program should be written like this:
   `

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     int main (void)
     {
     int fahr;
     double kelvin;
     printf ("Enter input \n");
     scanf("%d", &fahr);
     kelvin = (5/9)*(fahr-32) + 273.15;
     printf ("you get %f. \n", kelvin);
     return (0);  
     }
```

`

Comment: You can also ignore the return statement, if you use void main() instead of int main(void)